# how to use filter a list and append to stringbuilder using stream() java8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list which I need to iterate on the basis of certain conditions as below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
list.stream().forEach(l-> {
    if(l.contains("(")){
      sb.append("a");
    } else
      sb.append("b");
    });
```

How to do the same operation using filter of stream.

Comment: If the builder has to be empty initially, and you need to join "a" or "b" based on the iterations, then use `Collections.joining` as with transformation under `map` as `l.contains("(") ? "a" : "b"` once you stream.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this,

```
List<String> val = Arrays.asList("There", "(may)", "(not)", "exist", "brackets");
        StringBuilder sb = val.stream()
           .map(a -> a.contains("(")? "a": "b")
           .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::append,StringBuilder::append);
        System.out.println(sb);
```

`Output:`

baabb

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and put your condition

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
list.stream().map(str -> {
  if (str.contains("(")) {
    return "a";
  }
  return "b";
}).forEach(sb::append);
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not exactly what you asked for, but I thought it was worth presenting as an idea to consider.

```
    List<String> list = List.of("There", "(may)", "(not)", "exist", "brackets");
    String result = list.stream()
            .map(s -> s.contains("(") ? "a" : "b")
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is:

> baabb

Stream operations should generally be free from side effects, and their effect rather come out of their terminal operation. If you do need a `StringBuilder`, construct one after the end of the stream opeartion:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(result);
```